# react-native,Could not invoke ModuelAndroid.measureLayout

Tags: android, react-native

[error pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5Av1.jpg)

if i dont add note in the front of GpPrintService zonyService=new GpPrintService() in android code(GpPrintService.java).i get this error that like the pic.
The Class of GpPrintService Doc :

Constructor Summary

Constructor and Description
GpPrintService()

Comment: Can you post your code

Comment: one method 
    
    @ReactMethod
    public void entryPrinter(Callback errorCallback,CallBack successCallback){
        GpPrintService GPrinterService=new GpPrintService();
        try {
             successCallback.invoke(1);
        } catch (IllegalViewOperationException e) {
             errorCallback.invoke(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

Comment: the index.android.js user the method code,NativeModules.ModuleAndroid.entryPrinter((error)=>{alert(error)},(inf)=>{alert(inf);})

Comment: Instead of commenting your code, it is better if you edit your question and add the code there.

Comment: Are you getting the same error still? Can you post the error log as well.